# Why is that the before content doesnt contain within the button. i always have this issue designing buttons

Tags: css

*****The below code makes the before content flow outside the button itself. what should I do to contain it within the button**
***I need a parameter that fits the before content inside the button itself****........................................................................................................................................................................
===================================================**

```css
    button {
      padding: 0.9em 2em;
      border: 2px solid #17C3B2;
      position: absolute;
      
      background-color: transparent;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #ddd;
      transition: .3s;
     display: block;
      font-family: inherit;
      color: #17C3B2;
      z-index: 1;
     }
     
     button::before {
      overflow: hidden;
      content: '';
      width: 0;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;

     background: #17C3B2;
      transition: .5s ease;
      display: block;
      z-index: ;
     }
     
     button span {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 10%;
      height: 10%;
      background: transparent;
      z-index: 1;
     
     }



     button span::before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 8%;
      height: 500%;
      background: var(--lightgray);
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-60deg);
      transition: all 0.3s;
     }
     

    button:hover::before {
      position: absolute;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(44deg);
      width: 100%;
     }
     
     button:hover {
      color: #111;
     }
```

```html
    <button>hover me
    <span></span>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have added `overflow: hidden;` to the `button` and `z-index: -1;` to `button:hover::before`

```css
    button {
      padding: 0.9em 2em;
      border: 2px solid #17C3B2;
      position: absolute;
      
      background-color: transparent;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #ddd;
      transition: .3s;
     display: block;
      font-family: inherit;
      color: #17C3B2;
      z-index: 1;
      overflow: hidden;
     }
     
     button::before {
      overflow: hidden;
      content: '';
      width: 0;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;

     background: #17C3B2;
      transition: .5s ease;
      display: block;
      z-index: ;
     }
     
     button span {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 10%;
      height: 10%;
      background: transparent;
      z-index: 1;
     
     }



     button span::before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 8%;
      height: 500%;
      background: var(--lightgray);
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-60deg);
      transition: all 0.3s;
     }
     

    button:hover::before {
      position: absolute;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(44deg);
      width: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
     }
     
     button:hover {
      color: #111;
     }
```

```html
    <button>hover me
    <span></span>
    </button>
```

Comment: Hi, it's not clear to me what you want the final result to be. What is to be rotated? Just the background color of the before or the whole button or...? Running your snippet the background 'stripe' is contained within the button when I hover so I dont understand the problem.

Comment: I am looking to rotate the buttons after field like a minute hand on wall clock. I got the result from someone on the same group. I am just trying to design some more buttons and I encountered this issue. Frankly speaking I am new at this. So stumbling on several things